# SQL Injection comments not working properly?

Tags: sql, comments, sql-injection

The following command allows a successful login regardless of the password:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'eve'-- and password = 'asdasdasd';`

Because it ignores everything after the "--"

But the following command does not:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'eve'--' and password = 'asdasdasd';`

for some reason because of the extra apostrophe, when using sql injection generated from the following SQL command:

`"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "';"`

and using the following inputs:
username: eve' -- 
password: asdasdasd

Why should it care that there is a single apostrophe after the comment operator???
And what would be the correct input such that it will ignore the rest?

Thank you

Comment: Please tell us what language you are using here.  Also note that injection can be largely avoided by using your database's prepared statement API.

Comment: What happens for the 2nd example?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the language is SQL

Comment: @dnoeth the injection fails

Comment: @Stratadox I am trying to figure out why the injection fails when there is a second apostrophe

Comment: @Rahman so you're trying to hack someone's website?

Comment: You have an extra space between the single quote and the double quote, repeatedly.

Comment: @Rahman If you're trying to prevent SQL injection attacks, just use SQL parameters.

Comment: ...and if you're trying to inject someone's website...don't

Comment: @GMB that was for readability. It was unclear in the preview whether it was three singles, a single-double or a double-single. Anyway that is not the issue.

Comment: It is my own website set up specifically to learn sql. As if saying "dont hack" would work lol

Comment: *fails* How exactly does it fail, is there an error message?

Comment: @dnoeth It just does not return the user record I would assume. It fails to login. The command works perfectly when I supply the correct username and password however, so I know the login functionality works.

Comment: What's the DBMS?, MySQL has spme strange rules regarding `--` comments without following space

Comment: FYI "SQL" is not enough to specify the language because every database has its own dialect and quirks

Answer (score 0):

There must be a space following the `--` characters, at least in MySQL.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-comments.html says:

> Standard SQL uses “--” as a start-comment sequence. MySQL Server uses `#`
>   as the start comment character. MySQL Server also supports a variant of the `--` comment style. That is, the `--` start-comment sequence must
>   be followed by a space (or by a control character such as a newline).
>   The space is required to prevent problems with automatically generated
>   SQL queries that use constructs such as the following, where we
>   automatically insert the value of the payment for payment:
>
> ```
> UPDATE account SET credit=credit-payment
> ```
>
> Consider about what happens
>   if payment has a negative value such as -1:
>
> ```
> UPDATE account SET credit=credit--1
> ```
>
> `credit--1` is a valid expression in
>   SQL, but `--` is interpreted as the start of a comment, part of the
>   expression is discarded. The result is a statement that has a
>   completely different meaning than intended:
>
> ```
> UPDATE account SET credit=credit
> ```
>
> The statement produces no change in
>   value at all. This illustrates that permitting comments to start with
>   `--` can have serious consequences.